# linux to reduce the temp log file size

Tags: linux

We are getting log mails which has the data with dates and we are sending to our mails as attachements using mail command.

Sometimes the attachment crossing 500kb and making out inbox space full. How can we reduce the attachments to less kb , Do we have any tool in linux to reduce the size.

Thanks.,

Comment: Have you tried compressing it? `gzip` should do the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zip tool in linux compressed the log file in less size and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate can help you:
http://linuxconfig.org/logrotate-8-manual-page
The size parameter

```
Log files are rotated only if they grow bigger then size bytes.
```

And logrotate can send you a log file by mail too.

Comment: We are grepping the last 1 hr log from the original log. and sending to our mails as attachment - how to reduce the size of attachment using mailx command or do we have any tool